# Auto format gridview(Asp.net) on runtime

Tags: asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu

How can I **format** the **`gridview`** in asp.net on run time.  Using the `autoformat template`?

For example, there is a `gridview control`, and there is `dropdown list`, inside the dropdownlist are the autoformat templates.

And I need  to change the design of the `gridview` by just choosing from the dropdown list or is it even possible?

Comment: You stand a better change of getting answers if your question shows some researc heffort.

Comment: Every thing is possible. Have u tried any thing yet. Paste you code so that we can look and help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, read carefuly [`GridView Examples for ASP.NET 2.0: Formatting the GridView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479342.aspx). Then, on your dropdown list `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event, you can format which cell or column you want.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"
 OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_OnSelectedIndexChanged">
```

[`Accessing a DropDownList inside a GridView`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/53559/Accessing-a-DropDownList-inside-a-GridView)